# android convert file of size > 1gb to byte array

Tags: android, file, byte

I want convert the data to byte array. so that, i can send it over the network. For small file it is working. but for file of size>900 mb, am getting runtime exception. Here is my code.

```
 try {            
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            is.close();
            return byteBuffer;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Which exception do you get? There is an android setting tag called use large heap. Or something similar. Try to use this.

Comment: i deeply believe you mean one MB,  not one GB

Comment: Don't read 1GB into memory on an Android device! Really, don't do this. Most Android devices will keel over. Look at `MappedByteBuffer`, which does what you want: it allows you to treat the file almost as if it's in RAM, but it's actually still on disk. You can then send it, chunk by chunk, over the network.

Comment: @pskink Hmm, I'd like to think so, but the ">1GB" in the title matches nicely (or horribly) with the ">900MB" in the question.